# How can I load user data in a Keycloak .ftl template?

Tags: keycloak, freemarker

I have a custom login-update-password.ftl file. I want to show the user's firstname and lastname. In the template file of the base example I see `${username}` which lets me show the username. But when I do `${firstname}`, following happens:

```
12:25:46,752 ERROR [freemarker.runtime] (default task-3) Error executing FreeMarker template: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> firstname  [in template "login-update-password.ftl" at line 14, column 3]
```

When I do `${user.firstname}`, following happens:

```
12:27:40,453 ERROR [freemarker.runtime] (default task-2) Error executing FreeMarker template: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> user  [in template "login-update-password.ftl" at line 14, column 3]
```

I debugged the available variables, but nothing seems to be what I need.

```
<#list .data_model?keys as key>
  ${key}
</#list>
```

```
msg
execution
social
auth
isAppInitiatedAction
requiredActionUrl
message
locale
authenticatorConfigured
login
url
messagesPerField
client
realm
kcSanitize
scripts
properties
username
```

How can I load more user data?

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this question is super old but stumbled on it when I was trying to achieve this as well.

After some time I managed to figure it out, and can post my solution here in case someone else is reaching this question.

In my case I was using a custom authenticator and needed to set the "user" attribute before creating the form, e.g.

```
@Override
public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
    Response input = context.form().setAttribute("user", context.getUser()).createForm(MY_TEMPLATE_HERE);
    context.challenge(input);
}
```

I'm assuming that you are also using a custom authenticator since you're using a custom template.

Comment: I am not using a custom authenticator, just a custom theme. And I would not know where to put your code, it seems like Java, which I don't write.

Comment: Then you might be out of luck, Keycloak is built on java (Qurakus) from my understanding and if you don't have the user object available in the authenticator the only thing I can think of is to either create a new custom one https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#implementing-an-authenticator you could also extend the existing one if you manage to find out which one it is. 
Not an expert using keycloak so might be wrong here.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of (user.firstname) try the getFirstName method.
ex: user.getFirstName()

Comment: The user variable is missing. Therefore I receive the same error like above when I tried `${user.firstname}`. So when I do `${user.getFirstName()}` I also receive `The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> user ....` .

Comment: Also if `${user.getFirstName()}` worked (yes, it doesn't), then the nicer form is `${user.firstName}` (not `get` and `()`, and `Name` is capital).